# Get the domain name in Configuration of Startup.cs

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

In my ConfigureServices method of Startup.cs I have the following code in order to define the supported cultures and the default request culture:

```
var supportedCultures = new[]
{
    new CultureInfo("en-US"),
    new CultureInfo("el-GR"),
};
var MyOptions = new RequestLocalizationOptions()
{
    DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture(culture: "en-US", uiCulture: "en-US"),
    SupportedCultures = supportedCultures,
    SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures
};
MyOptions.RequestCultureProviders = new[]
{
        new RouteDataRequestCultureProvider() { RouteDataStringKey = "lang", Options = MyOptions }   
};

services.AddSingleton(MyOptions);
```

My problem is that the default request culture should be determined depending on the domain name. Is there a way to get the domain name inside the ConfigureServcies method?

Comment: I expect this isn’t going to be easy (or maybe even possible). You may want to consider just using a configuration value for this; whether that’s the domain name or the culture.

Comment: The problem is that all the sites use the same folder and all the web sites just show the folder that the application has been stored. This means that all the sites will have the same configuration file. The only way to do it is by identifying the domain name of the application.